# django auto login after UserCreationForm

Tags: django

I'm using one function to sign up and sign in user. The sign-in is working smoothly, however, when the user is registered it doesn't automatically login into his dashboard. Any suggestions? Thank you.

form:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','username','password1','password2',)
        labels = {
            'email' : 'Email address',
        }
```

.view:

```
def index(request):
    # SIGN UP
    form = SignUpForm()
    login_form = CustomAuthForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():


                auth.login(request)


                form.save();
                messages.success(request, "Successfully registered.")
                return redirect("dashboard")
        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_in':
           #Log in
            login_form = CustomAuthForm(data = request.POST)
            if login_form.is_valid():
                username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, "Successfully logged in.")
                    return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                messages.success(request, "Error credentials.")
    else:
        messages.success(request, "Error.")
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'form':form,'login_form':login_form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log in the user that you constructed with that form, so:

```
def index(request):
    form = SignUpForm()
    login_form = CustomAuthForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Successfully registered.')
                return redirect("dashboard")
    # …
```